# HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS across Windows versions

Tags: windows, winapi, process, nt-native-api

I can't find any documentation about this. I'm enumerating process handles in another process.

I check the value of `SYSTEM_HANDLE::ObjectTypeNumber` and apparently it's different between versions of Windows. I found this piece of code in a project on GitHub

```cpp
// For XP & 2K3 : HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS = 0x5
// For Vista & Longhorn : HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS = 0x6
// Windows 8: HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS = 0x7
#define HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS 7
```

Strangely, it skips Windows 7. I've been checking various kernel related books (such as Windows Internals) and wasn't able to find the correct value for Windows 7. I don't own a Windows 7 machine to test on either.

Therefore, my code looks like this at the moment:

```cpp
BYTE HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS;
if(IsWindows8OrGreater()) HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS = 7;
else if(IsWindowsVistaOrGreater()) HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS = 6;
else HANDLE_TYPE_PROCESS = 5;
```

What's the object type number for process handles in Windows 7?

Comment: It's never correct to rely on unverified assumptions. What's the question you really meant to ask?

Comment: I'm asking what's the value object type number of a process handle in Windows 7, it's undocumented

Comment: you need not hardcode it - this is always wrong and bad but found this in runtime

Comment: @RbMm Alright, but how exactly am I supposed to know if a handle is a process handle if not by comparing `ObjectTypeNumber`  to a compile-time constant?

Comment: you not need any compile-time constant. how - depend from what you need. if you interesting only in process - create by self process handle - look what `ObjectTypeIndex` it have - all another processes have the same. if you need for all object types - call `ZwQueryObject` with `ObjectAllTypeInformation` and look for `TypeIndex` begin from win 8.1. before this use returned record order and one known type index value which you take by way #1

Comment: Why not just call a function that requires a process handle, like `GetProcessId`. It's even documented and everything.

Comment: @RaymondChen - in most case this will be very not efficient and not working for all case solution (if we say can not duplicate handle to self process).

Comment: @RaymondChen The purpose is to see which process is being opened through other processes

Comment: @shavit - you need code like this - https://pastebin.com/QSWjya3D, or for more extended task (you need know all type index - use `ObjectAllTypeInformation`)

Comment: I should've specified, I'm working from usermode

Comment: @shavit - and so what ? how this related ?

Comment: The type index is from the system initialization order, so hard coding it for different Windows versions is dubious. You can query it via `NtQueryObject`: [`ObjectTypesInformation`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/6728482a11a2368196c4674b431acc5668e1683d/phnt/include/ntobapi.h#L91) in Windows 8.1+. Otherwise it's in [`SystemObjectInformation`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/6728482a11a2368196c4674b431acc5668e1683d/phnt/include/ntexapi.h#L1754), but that's expensive. Best to follow @RbMm's suggestion to check the type index of a known process handle.